# Angular ngInit formatting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a MEAN app and I'm trying to pass in data from the server-side into the angular application and I've read that this is possible with the use of [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) but I'm having a lot of trouble with getting it to work.

My Express route is set up as follows:

```
app.get('/dashboard', Auth.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/views/admin.html', req);
    console.log(req.user);
});
```

The console log message is there for production reasons so I can see the current authenticated user in the terminal.

Now when I try to pass req into ngInit and I'm getting tonnes of errors. If my body is set up like:

```
<body class="dashboard" ng-controller="DashboardController as dashboard" ng-init="active_user = {req.user}"> ... </body>
```

This causes angular to spit out:
[image: angular console]

Comment: You know, that you node.js code and you angular.js do not share the same variables. You explicitly need to pass the user into the rendered HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending a plain html file with `res.sendfile(…)` and expecting Express to interpolate a variable.

In order to do what you're asking you'll need to do some server-side templating. It looks like `res.render('admin', {user: req.user});` will do the trick, assuming you've modified your admin view to be a proper template.

Comment: Yeah I realised that mistake after I published this, I'm now rendering an EJS file and I'm still getting the same error with ng-init. However if I write a script in the head that that outputs `user` when `user` is defined as `<%- JSON.stringify(user) %>` - then the user is successfully logged out but I don't really want any embedded scripts.

Comment: Without more info I'm not sure how to help, did you try rendering `ng-init='active_user = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>;'`?